# Python NumPy: Performing different column operations over every N rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large `NumPy` array (`OriginalArray`) with many rows and 8 columns.

I want to create a new array (`NewArray`) in which each row has the following properties:

- Columns 1, 3, 5, and 7 of `NewArray` are the `sum` over `N` rows of columns 1, 3, 5, and 7 of `OriginalArray`
- Columns 2, 4, 6, and 8 of `NewArray` are the `mean` over `N` rows of columns 2, 4, 6, and 8 of `OriginalArray`

So, the `NewArray` has `1/N` as many rows as the `OriginalArray`.

For example:

```
Original Array = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
                  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
                  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
```

with `N = 2`

```
NewArray = [2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
            2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1]
```

Please excuse the messy formatting. I'm still very new at this (my first question here, actually).

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I was playing around with reshaping the array and slicing it to get the desired output. Your comment is very helpful, actually. Posting code (however amateurish) is the best way to get the most out of this site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach making heavy usage of [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) -

```
nrows = a.shape[0]//N  # a is input array
out = np.empty((nrows,8))
out[:,::2] = a[:,::2].reshape(-1,N,4).sum(1)
out[:,1::2] = a[:,1::2].reshape(-1,N,4).mean(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [64]: a     # Input array
Out[64]: 
array([[5, 1, 5, 8, 5, 0, 3, 1],
       [0, 7, 8, 7, 0, 3, 5, 1],
       [8, 6, 6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 2],
       [4, 5, 5, 7, 5, 2, 1, 2]])

In [65]: N = 2 # Summing/averaging length

In [66]: a[:,::2] # Select [1,3,5,7] cols
Out[66]: 
array([[5, 5, 5, 3],
       [0, 8, 0, 5],
       [8, 6, 1, 1],
       [4, 5, 5, 1]])

In [67]: a[:,::2].reshape(-1,N,4).sum(1) # Sum N rows by splitting axis
Out[67]: 
array([[ 5, 13,  5,  8],
       [12, 11,  6,  2]])

In [68]: a[:,1::2] # Select [2,4,6,8] cols
Out[68]: 
array([[1, 8, 0, 1],
       [7, 7, 3, 1],
       [6, 4, 6, 2],
       [5, 7, 2, 2]])

In [69]: a[:,1::2].reshape(-1,N,4).mean(1) # Similarly average across N rows
Out[69]: 
array([[ 4. ,  7.5,  1.5,  1. ],
       [ 5.5,  5.5,  4. ,  2. ]])
```

Comment: @VivianT Awesome! Glad to help you out.

Comment: Sorry! Just did this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your `original_array` (note the PEP8 style) is already formatted in rows and columns. By this I mean, `original_array = np.array([[1,1...],[1,...],[1,...],[1,...]])`

An easy one-liner to create a single row of `new_array` would be as follows:

```
import numpy as np
row = [np.sum(original_array[:,x]) if x%2==1 else np.mean(test[:,x]) for x in range(len(original_array[0]))]
```

And then to copy the row, simply:

```
new_array = [row]*N
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out.